# If a tensor space is a vector space, then why isn't a tensor a vector?

Tags: vectors, tensors

On page 78 of *Tensor
Analysis on Manifolds*, Bishop and Goldberg state:

*Let $V$ be a vector space. The scalar-valued multilinear functions with variables all in either $V$ or $V^*$ are called tensors over $V$ and the vector spaces they form are called the tensor spaces over $V$.*

I thought a vector was a tensor and not the other way around. I know a tensor is a multilinear map from a set of vector spaces and dual spaces onto $\Bbb{R}$.

Is a vector a tensor or a tensor a vector? Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: In math, a vector is an element of a vector space, so the term "vector space" is really the primary one and the term "vector" by itself comes later. There is no further content than that. (Physicists may use a different definition in terms of behavior under coordinate transformations.) If you build a new vector space from old ones then elements of the new space are vectors as well. A tensor product of vector spaces is an example of a new vector space. Calling its elements tensors is just part of remembering how they were created. But they are vectors as well.

Comment: If you start off with a vector space $V$, the standard tensor spaces created from it are $V^{\otimes k} \otimes (V^*)^{\otimes \ell}$ for nonnegative integers $k$ and $\ell$. Taking $k = 1$ and $\ell = 0$, this tensor space is just $V$, so elements of $V$ are tensors but in a *boring* way.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Why do you place the tensor product symbol in the superscript slot? That is, what does it signify?

Comment: It means a tensor product of $k$ copies of $V$ and $\ell$ copies of $V^*$. Would you rather write $a^{10}$ or $aaaaaaaaaa$?

Comment: Lol point taken. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3):

A tensor is a vector of the tensor space $T^{(m, n)}(V)$, which is itself forms a vector space.

A tensor space $T^{(m, n)}(V)$ is defined over a vector space $V$ as the set of functions $f$ with domain/image:

$$
T^{(m, n)}(V) = \{ f : V^m \times (V^*)^n \to \mathbb{R} \}
$$

Members of $T^{(m, n)}(V)$ are therefore of course different from members of $V$, one obvious reason is that they have the different dimensions in general: $dim(V)$ vs $dim(V) ^ {m \times n}$

Although all vector spaces of same dimension are isomorphic, the tensor space has a bit more structure than just the underlying vector space: we need to specify $m$ and $n$ for it as well. So given a arbitrary vector space $W$ it doesn't make much sense to say that members of that space are tensors unless we specify more information about which tensor space we are talking about by giving $m$ and $n$.

One identification that is natural to make is identify vectors of v of V as (0, 1) tensors over V. By definition, a (0, 1) tensor is a function T(f) that:

- takes a dual vector $f$ as input, where $f$ by definition of dual space is a funcation that maps a vector v of V to a number
- and outputs a number

Therefore, given $v$, we can create a (0, 1) tensor as:

$$
T(f) = f(v)
$$